# Vue InertiaJS Laravel - deletion request doesn't work

Tags: laravel, vue.js, request, inertiajs

im trying to make deletion request to `users.destroy`, i made sure that `ids` array returns an array of at least one element, when the request is made i get error from laravel : `count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, string given`

`Users/Index.vue`

```
const deleteSelectedUsers = () => {
    const ids = [];
    selectedUsers.value.forEach((val) => {
        ids.push(val.id);
    });

    router.delete(
        route("users.destroy", {
            user: ids,
        })
    );

    deleteUsers.value = false;
    selectedUsers.value = null;
    toast.add({
        severity: "success",
        summary: "Successful",
        detail: "Users Deleted",
        life: 3000,
    });
};
```

`UserController.php`

```
    public function destroy(Request $request)
    {

         try {
            DB::table('users')->whereIn('id', $request->user)->delete();
        } catch (Throwable $e) {
           dd($e);
        }

    }
```

also the `query builder` statement doesn't work anyway, i tried to give it a fixed array and it didn't delete any rows with the specified `id`:

```
         $delete = DB::table('users')->whereIn('id', [5,27])->delete();
```

Comment: what error are you expecting?

Comment: anything so i could know what is the problem

Comment: unless you pass empty array on that delete statement, it will never throw an error, this line `DB::table('users')->whereIn('id', [6,25])->delete();` will return `1` if its deleted anything or `0` if deleted nothing.

Comment: maybe you have softDelete on user model? did you try `->forceDelete()`? instead of `->delete()`

Comment: i don't have softDelete on model, the function wasn't even sending the request, i forgot to wrap ```route()``` inside of ```router.delete()```, now im getting an error, i updated my post to show the error, the query builder statement doesn't work anyway because i also tried to give it a fixed array and it didn't delete any rows, this query builder doesn't give a shit anyway

Comment: do `dd($request->all() );` on the first line of your destroy method, it says you are not passing an array.  also, install [clockwork](https://github.com/itsgoingd/clockwork), you can easily inspect db execution and calls when you made the request

Comment: ```ids``` is indeed an array, but when it gets sent it becomes just string for some reason, it worked after i manually converted it to array in the server side ```$delete = DB::table('users')->whereIn('id', [$request->user])->delete();```, thank you @silver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce the same error by execute `whereIn` with `null`:

```php
DB::table('users')->whereIn('id', null)->delete();
```

It's best to assume that `$request->user` is null in your controller.
I'm not sure how Laravel handles incoming **DELETE** request, but it's possible that Laravel were ignoring your request body for http **DELETE** request, leading to `$request->user` being null.

One way to test this problem is by switching your http request from **DELETE** to **POST**.